# PHPmailer how to show message

Tags: php, jquery, phpmailer

How I can show success message after to click send in my form? my phpmailer is working but I want to also after to click send to redirect to my homepage (index.html) and show my message div. This is my php code.

```
<?php
require 'phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer;

$subject = $_POST['subject'];
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

//$mail->SMTPDebug = 3;                               // Enable verbose debug output

$mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host = 'mail.xxxxxxx.pl';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = 'xxxxx@xxxxxxxx.pl';                 // SMTP username
$mail->Password = 'password';                           // SMTP password
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
$mail->Port = 587;                                    // TCP port to connect to

$mail->setFrom($email, $name);
$mail->addAddress('xxxx@gmail.com', 'xxxxxxxx');     // Add a recipient              // Name is optional

$mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML

$mail->Subject = $subject;
$mail->Body    = 'Body test';


if(!$mail->send()) {
    echo 'Message could not be sent.';
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
   header('Location: index.html');

}
```

And this is my Jquery code to show/hidden div succes:

```
$('.box-up').animate({top : 150}, 'normal').delay(3000).animate({top : -500}, 'normal');
```

Comment: you'd have to store the message somewhere, and then arrange for your html page to display it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could send extra parameter with your request :

```
header('Location: index.php?r=1');
```

Then in your index page get the parameter and use it to show the box :

```
<script>
    var result="<?php echo $_GET['r']; ?>";

    if(parseInt(result)){
        $('.box-up').animate({top : 150}, 'normal').delay(3000).animate({top : -500}, 'normal');
    }
</script>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: so i must save index.html as index.php and this code add in my js file?

Comment: You should debug to know from where come the problem, try for example to show `alert(result);`;

Comment: when i debug with alert, return number 1 so this should works but this jquery not worrk. In my localhost this jquery work normal show and hide div.